# How to Make JSON from Array of Struct in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, serialization, swift3

I have a problem to make a `JSON` from an array of struct in `Swift3`. I searched in `Stack Overflow`, nothing help me (here the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/dfwri2)). I have a `struct` like this:

```
public struct ProductObject {
    var prodID: String
    var prodName: String
    var prodPrice: String
    var imageURL: String
    var qty: Int
    var stock: String
    var weight: String

    init(prodID: String, prodName: String, prodPrice: String, imageURL: String, qty: Int, stock: String, weight: String){
        self.prodID = prodID
        self.prodName = prodName
        self.prodPrice = prodPrice
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.qty = qty
        self.stock = stock
        self.weight = weight
    }
}
```

and the array of that struct:

```
private var productsArray = [ProductObject]()
```

When the array is not empty, and then I tried to print it in another class, it shows this in debugger:

```
[app.cartclass.ProductObject(prodID: "2", prodName: "produk 2", prodPrice: "IDR 1000000", imageURL: "someURL", qty: 1, stock: "11", weight: "200")]
```

The array is not a valid `JSON object`. How to make it a valid `JSON` object? And I wonder whether this part "app.cartclass.ProductObject" is a problem or not to make it a valid `JSON object`?

edit:

Here's how I serialize into a `JSON`:

```
var products = [String:Any]()
    for j in 0 ..< cart.numberOfItemsInCart()  {
        products=["\(j)":cart.getAllProduct(atIndex: j)]
    }
    if let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(products) {
        do {
            let jsonproducts = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: products, options: .prettyPrinted) as! [String:Any]
            //print(jsonproducts)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
     } else {
         print("it is not a valid JSON object");
     }
```

Comment: why dont you wana use class in place of struct ?

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari because in class cartclass there are a lot of other things to do

Comment: then use nsjsonserialization to convert it into json data

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari as I stated above, it's not a valid JSON object, that's why I ask for help to change it into a valid one. It throws an error.

Comment: how you converting it , where is that code ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to make JSON from custom object then first you need to convert your custom object to `Dictionary`, so make one function like below in your `ProductObject` struct.

```
func convertToDictionary() -> [String : Any] {
    let dic: [String: Any] = ["prodID":self.prodID, "prodName":self.prodName, "prodPrice":self.prodPrice, "imageURL":self.imageURL, "qty":qty, "stock":stock, "weight":weight]
    return dic
}
```

Now use this function to generate Array of dictionary from Array of custom object `ProductObject`.

```
private var productsArray = [ProductObject]()
let dicArray = productsArray.map { $0.convertToDictionary() }
```

Here `dicArray` is made of type `[[String:Any]]`, now you can use `JSONSerialization` to generate `JSON` string from this `dicArray`.

```
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dicArray, options: .prettyPrinted) {
    let str = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(str)
}
```

Comment: It's working! So, that my way of translating into Dictionary is wrong. Thank you very much!