# How can I convert an array with custom classes to JSON in swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

I need to create the following json in swift 3 and I don't want to use external libraries.
I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28325471/5670425) but I'm using custom classes (store and product) inside the array, so it doesn't work.

```
"order": 
    [{
        "store": 1,
        "product": [ 
        {
            "id": 1,
            "quantity": 1 
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "quantity": 5 
        }]
    },
    {
        "store": 4, 
        "product": [ {
            "id": 1,
            "quantity": 1 
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "quantity": 1 
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make JSON from Array of Struct in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989483/how-to-make-json-from-array-of-struct-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can accmoplish this with the following:

1) Create a toJSON() function in your object's class

2) Make a dictionary in this object that stores the properties and their values.

Here's an example of a couple of small classes based off your json example:

```
class Order {

    var store: Store!
    var products: [Product]!

    init(store: Store, products: [Product]) {
        self.store = store
        self.products = products
    }

    func toJSON() -> [String : Any] {
        var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]

        dictionary["store"] = store.toJSON()

        var productsDictionary: [Int : Any] = [:]

        for index in 0...self.products.count - 1 {
            let product: Product = products[index]
            productsDictionary[index] = product.toJSON()
        }

        dictionary["product"] = productsDictionary

        return dictionary
    }
}


class Store {

    var id: Int!

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

    func toJSON() -> [String:Any] {
        var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]

        dictionary["id"] = self.id

        return dictionary
    }
}

class Product {
    var id: Int!
    var quantity: Int!

    init(id: Int, quantity: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.quantity = quantity
    }

    func toJSON() -> [String:Any] {
        var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]

        dictionary["id"] = self.id
        dictionary["quantity"] = self.quantity

        return dictionary
    }
}
```

3) Follow the example link you posted

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(order.toJSON(), options: nil, error: nil)
```

Comment: What if I want an array of products? How should I do it? Right now it only adds 1 product & 1 store.

Comment: There are definitely a couple ways you could do this. You could just loop through your array of products in your Order.toJSON() function and add each product to the dictionary. See my edits to the Order object for an example. Might need some restructuring depending on how you want to store the products in the JSON object though.

Comment: @Marchu if there is more I can do to make this a more acceptable answer, please let me know. If this answer satisfies your needs please mark as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your classes called "ToDictionary" that returns a dictionary hand-coded with your fields and values. Then just call NSJSONSerialization on that dictionary. Under ObjC you could use reflection, but that's not here yet...

Comment: refer this for reflections - https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/