# how to create json object in ios swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have 3 arrays when I insert data inside table than that data also add in the array (key, value pair).

```
var person = ["ABC","XYZ","PQR"]
var email = ["abc@yahoo.com","xyz@yahoo.com","pqr@yahoo.com"]
var mobile = ["1234567890","1234567890","1234567890"]
```

My problem is how to create JSON object and data store key value pair.

I want this

```
{
    "blogs": [
        {
            "person": "ABC",
            "email": "abc@yahoo.com",
            "contact": "1234567890"
        },
        {
            "person": "XYZ",
            "email": "xyz@yahoo.com",
            "contact": "1234567890"
        },
{
            "person": "PQR",
            "email": "pqr@yahoo.com",
            "contact": "1234567890"
        }
    ]
}
```

so that data passes to `url()`

In the action button that adds data in array and table

```
@IBAction func meeting_info(_ sender: Any) {

        var PersonName = person_name.text
        var Email = email_id.text
        var MobileNo = mobile_no.text

        if (person_name.text?.isEmpty)! || (email_id.text?.isEmpty)! || (mobile_no.text?.isEmpty)!  {

            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "please check field empty or not");

        }

        else{

            person.append(person_name.text!)
            email.append(email_id.text!)
            mobile.append(mobile_no.text!)

            meetingTableView.reloadData()

        }



    }
```

I want to generate JSON array from person, email and contact in key value pairs

Answer (score 3):

to answer your question.

```
 var person = ["ABC","XYZ","PQR"]
    var email = ["abc@yahoo.com","xyz@yahoo.com","pqr@yahoo.com"]
    var mobile = ["1234567890","1234567890","1234567890"]


    var paramCollection = [Any]()

    var index = 0
    for personData in person {
        var dataCollection = [String:Any]()
        dataCollection["person"] = personData
        dataCollection["email"] = email[index]
        dataCollection["contact"] = mobile[index]
        paramCollection.append(dataCollection)
        index += 1
    }

    let finalParameter = ["blogs":paramCollection]
}

//This will do the trick but to make it more robust you should rethink your design
// maybe use struct to store a persons data
struct Blog {
    var person: String
    var email: String
    var mobile: String

    init(name:String, email:String, phone:String) {
        self.person = name
        self.email = email
        self.mobile = phone
    }
}

//and instead of having three arrays holding three different property, you can have one array of
var blogArray = [Blog]()

//You understand where I'm going with this
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great design by choice to have multiple arrays relating to the data of same Entity.

Ideally create an Entity Model called Blog with fields like personName, email, mobileNo like below -

```
struct Blog {

var personName: String?
var email: String?
var mobileNo: String?
}
```

And then in your code have an array of this to save the data then you can directly convert it into Json using the link

[Convert Custom Structs to Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989483/how-to-make-json-from-array-of-struct-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let jsonObject: [String: Any]?
let array: [[String: Any]] = [[:]]

    for i in 0..person.count {
    let dict = ["person": person[i],
        "email": email[i],
        "contact": mobile[i]]
    array.append(dict)
    }
    jsonObject = ["blogs": array]

let validateJson = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject)
if validateJson {
  //Go Ahead
}
```

Comment: I pass your value in one paramerter like

Comment: var sss = ["cutomer name":"xyz","date":"13-08-2017","blogs": array] as [String : Any] and coverter into jsonobject and that jsonobject pass to post web service.any probelm for future process

Answer (score 0):

```
let dictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"] 
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .prettyPrinted) 
// Verifying it worked: 
let parsedObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments)
```